# How can I save a variable from a database and use it in C#?

Tags: c#, database

I am changing a program and I need some help because I don't know C#. I change things with:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE materials SET ";
strSQL = strSQL + "Dscr = 'concrete', ";
strSQL = strSQL + "width=50 ";
strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE ID=385";
objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, db_def.conn);
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There is a case where I need to find an ID, store it and then use it again. So I use select

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM materials WHERE    Type=1", db_def.conn);
 OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (reader.HasRows)
 {
   reader.Read();
   var result = reader.GetInt32(0);
 }

 strSQL = "UPDATE materials SET ";
 strSQL = strSQL + "Dscr = 'concrete', ";
 strSQL = strSQL + "width=50 ";
 strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE ID=result";
 objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, db_def.conn);
 objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I get an error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this and tell  me if it works

```
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM materials WHERE    Type=1", db_def.conn);
     OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int result=-1 ;
     if (reader.HasRows)
     {
       reader.Read();
       result = reader.GetInt32(0);
     }
if (result != -1)
{
     strSQL = "UPDATE materials SET ";
     strSQL = strSQL + "Dscr = 'concrete', ";
     strSQL = strSQL + "width=50 ";
     strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE ID="+result;
     objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, db_def.conn);
     objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I did this and the error this time is:use of unassigned local variable "result"

Comment: I declared 'result' outside the ' If '

Comment: copy this or no? sorry i didn't undertsand

Comment: same thing, i did it and the answer is unassigned local variable result

Comment: try now this suggestion and sorry I have a problem to understand the englais

Comment: You can't put null into an int

Comment: IT WORKED!!! O THANK YOU SO MUCH. I AM A CIVIL ENGINEER AND MY DIPLOMATIC NEEDS PROGRAMMING.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful then please "Vote as Helpful" and "Mark As Answer". that help athore persone to find the answer easy

Answer (score 0):

Although your code that you're working on is less than desirable, I'll just provide the fix you require at this point:

Change your code to :

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM materials WHERE    Type=1", db_def.conn);
 OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int result=0;

 if (reader.HasRows)
 {
   reader.Read();
   result = reader.GetInt32(0);
 }

 strSQL = "UPDATE materials SET ";
 strSQL = strSQL + "Dscr = 'concrete', ";
 strSQL = strSQL + "width=50 ";
 strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE ID=" + result;
 objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, db_def.conn);
 objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You need to provide the value of the result variable outside the SQL string - the database will not know the value of 'result' in its own context.

EDIT: the `result` variable was declared within the if statement, therefore not available further down for assigning.

Comment: That's correct, but given the error provided by Kallia, and the intention, it's pretty clear this is accurate in this case. if there was a `column` in materials called `result`, this error would not have been raised.

Comment: i did it but the error now is : the name "result" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: there isn't a column with name result, result is just an variable.

Comment: I've updated the code to correct this issue - try using my edited code above.

Comment: i tried it but the problem now is Syntax error in FROM clause

Comment: Use the SQL profiler to look at the SQL that is being executed.  This way you can debug.

Comment: I think: strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE ID=result";

need to be: strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE ID= " + result;

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS.THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

Comment: With the other solution, its the same but we can't give null in an int.